# Using this.props.history on button onClick to navigate to another page reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When running this code, everything compiles, but when I click on the "Click me" button, instead of routing to "formPage.js", it throws an error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". How should I resolve this?

When I use "www.google.com" it instead of formPage.js it also throws me the same error.

Is there a way to go about resolving this without having to convert my entire code to function to use useHistory()?

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Form extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: []
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    async getData() {
        await axios.get("https://...")
        .then((response) => {
            const convertString = JSON.parse(response.data.body);
            this.setState({message: convertString});
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.props.history.push("/formPage.js");
    }

    render() {
        const obj = (this.state.message);
        const datamapping = Object.entries(this.state.message);
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="viewall">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <th scope="col">Click me</th>
                            <th scope="col">key1</th>
                            <th scope="col">key2</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {obj.Items?.map((data, key) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr key={key}>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                                                Click me
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{data.key1}</td>
                                        <td>{data.key2}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            })}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Most probably you should [wrap](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router) your component `withRouter` from the `react-router`. Also, you can check with `console.log(this.props)` in `render` method to see all the props of the component.

Comment: Hi thanks! Will check that out and let you know.

Comment: to use `useHistory()` you'll need to port that entire page to be a hook based component, which depending on your version / team might not be worth the effort

Comment: yup, this I know. So was wondering if there was an alternative method to this